# Is there any hint of of the first Wizarding War being an international event?

Tags: harry-potter

Is there any hint that the MoM or anywhere else got support in combating voldemort the first time around? Or is everything completely UK-centric?

I can't remember anyone in the *second* war being specifically sent from europe to help, even though we see international wizards in book 4. But I don't think all the events of the first war are covered in the books.

So are other bodies like the MoM involved in the first war, or was it isolated in the UK?

Comment: I don't have the quotes on me, but the photo of the first Order was british-only, and it was implied nobody but the Order and Aurors fought.

Comment: Also, Voldie had the help of Giants, werewolves, rustlers, cut throats, murderers, bounty hunters, desperados, mugs, pugs, thugs, nitwits, halfwits, dimwits, vipers, snipers, con men, Indian agents, Mexican bandits, muggers, buggerers, bushwhackers, hornswogglers, horse thieves, bull dykes, train robbers, bank robbers, ass-kickers, shit-kickers and Methodists.

Comment: 1st wizarding war= WW1

Comment: @sightward: I believe WWI corresponds more to the war with Grindelwald. (I'm putting together a longer answer, and JKR seems to confirm that.)

Comment: @alexwlchan i didnt mean that in a literal sense.Just that WW1 is an acronym to both world war 1 and wizarding war 1

Comment: @sightward: ah, sorry. My bad.

Comment: @alexwlchan So, uh...  Are you writing a book or did you end up not posting the longer answer? =P

Comment: @Izkata: thanks for the nudge. I forget to come back, so some of what I found it ended up in an answer here, instead: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47835/what-is-the-connection-between-grindelwald-and-world-war-ii/47838#47838 Whoops. :P

Answer (score 5):

It is implied that it is not an international event but that doesn't mean that it would not have escalated to that point given time. Tom Riddle was stopped in both wars before he could consolidate his power at home. I suspect that once he had secured his base of operations he would have started moving outwards (like Hitler.)

Comment: Where is it implied?

Answer (score 5):

### It seems unlikely that it was

All those who  are described as fighting against Voldemort in the First Wizarding War appear to have been British. On Voldemort's side, the only Death Eater who *might* have been a foreign wizard was Igor Karkaroff. On the other hand, Voldemort did have aid from some giants, but it is indicated that they may have been exiled to Continental Europe *after* the FWW. Had Voldemort been fighting agaist non-British witches and wizards as well, it would surely have been mentioned.

What's more, Voldemort had not even succeeding in overthrowing the Ministry by the end of the First Wizarding War. It would have been quite counterproductive for him to be fighting against dozens of other wizarding countries, some with significantly larger populations.

**So there is no evidence that the First Wizarding War took place anywhere but Britain, and it is unlikely that it did.**